# PHP - How to arrange array value , reset it's key and start key with 0 index?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I'm working on cart functionality in one of my projects. We are using Laravel 5.3 and cart item is stored in Laravel session as an array. So if I have 3 items in my cart (**add_to_cart** Laravel session) it looks like this:

```
array:3 [▼
        0 => array:6 [▼
       "sku" => "brs000500"
       "price" => "500"
       "quantity" => "1"
       "brand_id" => "1"
       "brand_name" => "Baskin Robbins"
       "brand_img" => "http://s3.giftcardsindia.in/2015/06/01/original-556c659cc05cf.jpg"
       ]
       1 => array:6 [▼
       "sku" => "fab001000"
       "price" => "1000"
       "quantity" => "1"
       "brand_id" => "6"
       "brand_name" => "Fabindia"
       "brand_img" =>"http://s3.giftcardsindia.in/2015/06/01/original-556c64882baa7.jpg"
       ]
       2 => array:6 [▼
      "sku" => "tnq010000"
      "price" => "10000"
      "quantity" => "1"
      "brand_id" => "46"
      "brand_name" => "Tanishq"
      "brand_img" => "http://s3.giftcardsindia.in/2015/06/01/original-556c47dd2ca85.jpg"
      ]
]
```

Now I have developed remove item from cart functionality using array key (index). So when user clicks on any item to remove it from cart I send key of that product array to controller function and using **unset array** function I remove whole array of particular key from session.

From above example let's assume that I have removed product of **key** 0 after that I got array as below:

```
array:1 [▼
   0 => array:2 [▼
      1 => array:6 [▼
      "sku" => "fab001000"
      "price" => "1000"
      "quantity" => "1"
      "brand_id" => "6"
      "brand_name" => "Fabindia"
      "brand_img" => "http://s3.giftcardsindia.in/2015/06/01/original-      556c64882baa7.jpg"
      ]
     2 => array:6 [▼
     "sku" => "tnq010000"
     "price" => "10000"
     "quantity" => "1"
     "brand_id" => "46"
     "brand_name" => "Tanishq"
     "brand_img" => "http://s3.giftcardsindia.in/2015/06/01/original-556c47dd2ca85.jpg"
     ]
  ]
]
```

When shown this structure is for sure not the same as when I stored item in cart.

So what I want is to remove first **key** of 0, for **key** 1 and 2 will be outside **key** 0 and result array will start with **key** 0.

In short, I need array structure like first example that I use here in question.

How to arrange this array structure?

Answer (score 0):

[array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) do it for you :)

`array_splice($cartArray, $key, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

From laravel docs :

> **array_except**
>
> The array_except method removes the given key / value pairs from the
>   array.
>
> $array = array_except($array, array('keys', 'to', 'remove'));

in your case you can do :

```
array_except($array, array(0));
```

removes child array with 0 key